# Read the center of an image with LibTiff.net

Tags: c#, geotiff, libtiff

I need to read the center of an image using the LibTiff library in C #,

This code read image in coordinates 0,0, i need read the center of image, according to the widht and height of the image:

```
            using (Tiff tiff = Tiff.Open(filename, "r"))
            {
                width = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
                int middleW = width / 2;
                height = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
                int middleH = height / 2;
                bits = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE)[0].ToInt();
                tiff.CurrentRow();

                var modelscale = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.GEOTIFF_MODELPIXELSCALETAG);
                var tiepoint = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.GEOTIFF_MODELTIEPOINTTAG);

                i = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0);
                j = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0 + 8);
                k = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0 + 16);
                x = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0 + 24);
                y = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0 + 32);
                z = BitConverter.ToDouble(tiepoint[1].ToByteArray(), 0 + 40);

             }
```

How i can read the center of an image for variables X and Z, with this library?